# Is there any way to install sample data from Zip file after successful installation of magento 2.3.5-p2?

Tags: sample-data, magento2.3.5-p2

I have installed Magento 2.3.5-p2. But after that i need to install sample data i exectute command

```
 - php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

- But i got this ..
  `Could not find a matching version of package magento/module-sales-sample-data. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable)`.

After that i have downloaded Zip file from mageplaza extract file and paste file in magento directory and execute command.

- **bin/magento setup:upgrade**

I got **Nothing to import.**

Is there any other way to install sample data. i am using apache2, php 7.2. i have installed each thing sepratelly not any xampp, lamp etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install sample data as a official composer package. See the instructions on the dev docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html.

Comment: I have tried but i does not work for me or i am unable to understand how it works..

Comment: Ok then try the following approach: Clone sample data from https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data. If your Magento instance was cloned from the master branch, choose the master branch when cloning sample data; choose the develop branch if Magento was cloned from develop.
Link the sample data and your Magento instance by running: # php -f <sample-data_clone_dir>/dev/tools/build-sample-data.php -- --ce-source="<path_to_your_magento_instance>". Replace sample-data_clone_dir with the directory where you have the sample data cloned and also replace path_to_your_magento_instance with

Comment: Also if your having issues after that, change the permissions `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento2/magento2-sample-data/` , where www-data:www-data is the group.

Comment: thanks it solve my issue.

Comment: @Manii great to hear, please upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another easiest way to install sample data and that also work for me so i want to share it may help some one ...
i have downloaded sample data zip file from here
https://www.mageplaza.com/download-magento/#download-Magento%202.
and then extract it and copy everything inside the extracted directory and then past it in magento2 folder and execute the follwing commands.

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento sampledata:deploy

after that i resest permissions

- chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
- chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
  and then set rewrite mod
- sudo a2enmod rewrite
- service apache2 restart
  and my issue is resolved.
  Hope it may help someone